# Passing ajax request in switch statement to php all in the same file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, daterangepicker

I understand that there are many SO articles about this which I looked into but I'm still having trouble. sending my data to my PHP fro my ajax request so I can use it in my MYSQL model. I know I should split this all in different files but was experimenting with how data is handled all in one file.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Send startDate, endDate from custom daterangepicker to PHP so I can use it in my query and eventually use it in my view. However, once I have access to the variables in php I'll know how to display it in the view I just want to know how to access the variables from my ajax request which I'm stuck on at the moment.

Here is my code:

**PHP w/ model query**

```php
<?php

  // This is where my problem is I need to grab ajax request from my post request but it says not defined? I also tried putting in exit in as well and did not work.
    if (isset($_POST['startDate'])) {
        echo 'Start date variable was sent.';
    } else {
        echo 'Start date variable was not sent.';
    }
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
        var end = moment();

        var startTotal = moment().subtract(2, 'year').startOf('year');

        function initDPicker(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D,      YYYY'));
        }

        $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(event, picker) {
            switch(picker.chosenLabel){
      // There are many other cases in my code but this is the specific case I'm trying to accomplish.

            case "Custom Range":
                canvas[0].id="customrange";

                var customStart = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate._d;
                var customEnd = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate._d;

                customStart = moment(customStart, 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                customEnd = moment(customEnd, 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                var data = {
                    "startDate": customStart,
                    "endDate": customEnd
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data : data,
                    success : function(result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });

                break;
            }         
        });
        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            start: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
               'Total': [moment().subtract(2, 'year').startOf('year'), moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY')],
               'Today': [moment(), moment()],
               'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
               'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
               'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
               'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
               // 'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, initDPicker);
    });
```

Here is screenshot of the successful network request. However, when I try to access this request on the same page in PHP, I do not have access to it.

[image]

Comment: Add a `var_dump($_POST)`  to see what your request looks like by the time it gets to your PHP.  Do you see your parameters there?

Comment: "I'm still having trouble"  And what exactly is the "trouble" that you're having? What's happening? What's are you expecting to happen? What debugging have you done?

Comment: the var dump of `$_POST` returns an array of 0. To answer the second comment, what I'm expecting to happen is after I initiate my ajax request, that I have access to those variables in PHP through POST but it doesn't return anything in the $_POST which I'm stuck on.

Comment: That request clearly has the POST vars in it, but if php has nothing in the $_POST superglobal, then either a redirect happened, or something further up in your code has unset or purged it?? Odd.

Comment: What are you seeing in your Javascript console as a result of your `console.log(result);`?

Comment: When i console.log ajax result, it outputs all the JavaScript and HTML in the page, except for the PHP code obviously.

Comment: You should be seeing either "Start date variable was sent." or "Start date variable was not sent." as part of the response.  Which are you getting?

Comment: Start date variable was not sent.

Comment: "when I try to access this request on the same page in PHP, I do not have access to it."  Could you try to explain what exactly you mean by this?  What is the "this request"?  What is the "it" that you "do not have access to "?  You're not expecting the $_POST variables to persist across requests, right?

Comment: I probably should of deleted that portion of the code it was placeholder code that I was going to use in my query once I figured out how to get access $_POST variables from the ajax request. I was going to set those post variables with $startDate $endDate. I'll delete that from my code so it won't confuse you.

Comment: Just to rule out any redirects or url-rewrites, add to your `.ajax` options the direct url to the php that should handle the post variables: `$.ajax({ url: '/path/to/my.php', ...`

Comment: I'll try this but 1 question: if I do a var dump on the same page I made the ajax request, will the var_dump update the array? Because what happens is the ajax request on page load, is 0 but the ajax request doesn't hit the network until I select a date from the daterangepicker. Also, I tried passing in the url in the ajax request, and it's going to the correct url and no re-directs are happening in my code. I even checked the network requests and it's going to the right page.

Comment: No, you should be looking at the `console.log()` of the response for the array dump. PHP cannot update html that is already rendered to the client.

Comment: Okay I think i know what my problem is, I'm dumping out the $_POST variable on page load in php, however, the ajax request doesn't hit my network until an update happens in the client so php doesn't know what the updated information is. I'll see if I can approach this a different way.

Comment: No, you just looked for the data in the wrong place and didnt update the page to show it, ie you didnt update the dom like, `document.body.innerHTML = response`. Doing an ajax request doesn't automagically change what your page contains, you have to manually do that.